# How can I pass variables from a form within the Wordpress platform?

Tags: php, email, wordpress, forms, variables

I'm building a website using Wordpress.  The **WP-Events plugin** is being used to display a list of upcoming events.  What I need is for people to be able to confirm their attendance at any particular event.

WP-Events is a bit awkward in that it's customised using a template that is only able to be edited with the Wordpress admin.   I used this template in combination with the Wordpress 'Loop' to generate a form for each event that could be filled in and submitted.  I then was going to use jquery to toggle the display of each form as to not make the page massive.  This plan collapsed when I wasn't able to implement any form validation.

What I have now is a list of events on one page, and a confirmation form on another.  What I now need is to **pull the event name, date and location from the selected event, and pass them across for use in the form**.  The problem is that wordpress' permalink structure doesn't seem to allow me to add a variable (ie. `example.php?variable=1` ).

It it possible to do this?

thanks in advance,
Greg.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you modified something, out of the box Wordpress will allow you to use GET variables, because it uses them too (for previewing posts).

If you installed something that removed all of the GET parameters, you might want to uninstall that. But out of the box Wordpress will let you use GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both GET and POST with no effect.  If you have PHP processing a GET variable on a WP Page, the URL is:

/page/?variable=something

And PHP is not recognizing this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use add_query_arg function. [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg).